# What is the U-Boot API?

Tags: u-boot

The U-Boot v2021.01 configuration menu has a configuration option `Enable U-Boot API` under the `API` section. The help page provided below isn't explanatory enough.

> This option enables the U-Boot API.

So, what actually is the U-Boot API? What kind of things does it offer us?

Comment: I found this by googling “u-boot api” is this what you’re looking for? https://u-boot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/index.html

Comment: @Fogmeister I'm not looking for something specific. I just saw the option and Googled it, but couldn't find an explanation. So the question popped up! The link you sent also doesn't have a direct explanation of what the API is. It just has the nitty-gritty details.

Comment: Ok, where did you see the option? Right now we have no context about what it is you’re asking for help with or where you saw the things you saw. If we could have some more details about what you’re trying to do it would help us to help you. For instance, you seem to have no idea what the u-boot api is which is fine. But why are you looking for it?

Comment: @Fogmeister I'm looking for it just to gain knowledge. I don't have any certain purpose in which I can utilize it, for now.. As I told, I saw it on the `menuconfig` page, under the API section. The U-Boot version is 2021.01 by the way.

Comment: Look at the code in the **examples/** directory of U-Boot source code.

Answer (score 1):

It is an API that can be used to create a standalone application that is run by U-Boot and then typically returns control to U-Boot.  In general, it's use is discouraged, and on modern systems if you must have a standalone application, using the EFI API instead is preferred.